# add vector/list to element of r dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe, and I would like to add a new column whose elements are themselves vectors (or lists).
The vectors/lists may might not be expressible in closed form.
I tried the following but received an error

```
> mydf = data.frame(a=1:3)
> mydf$new <-  vector('list', nrow(mydf))
> for(i in seq_len(nrow(mydf))) {
+   mydf$new[i] <- rep(i, ceiling(10 * runif(1)))
+ }
Warning messages:
1: In mydf$new[i] <- rep(i, ceiling(10 * runif(1))) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In mydf$new[i] <- rep(i, ceiling(10 * runif(1))) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In mydf$new[i] <- rep(i, ceiling(10 * runif(1))) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

What is the correct way?

---

Old question: how to populate a new column with `vs`

```
v1 = c(1,2,3)
v2 = c(4,5)
v3 = c(6,7,8,9,10)
vs = list(v1, v2, v3)
mydf = data.frame(a=1:3)
for (i in 1:3){
  v = rep(i, ceil(10 * runif(1)))
  mydf[i, "new"] = vs[i]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want to do this in a `for` loop, wrap the `rep` output in a `list`

```
mydf$new <- vector('list', nrow(mydf))
for(i in seq_len(nrow(mydf))) {
   mydf$new[i] <- list(rep(i, ceiling(10 * runif(1))))
 }
```

-output

```
> mydf
  a                 new
1 1             1, 1, 1
2 2          2, 2, 2, 2
3 3 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
```

Comment: I want different lists in each element, which is why I tried a for loop. What to do in that case?

Comment: thanks, I was hoping for a general approach

Comment: Sorry, is there a general way if i don't have the expression for the column in closed form?

Comment: I will again edit the Q. Appreciate your help refining the question

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: I need it in a for loop, i thought it would be a generic approach using a for loop

Comment: im sorry, it doesn't solve my underlying problem, which i realized was ill posed when i first asked

Comment: I thought my question would get answered in the way i needed, i didn't realize that i phrased it poorly

Comment: oh my gosh, im sorry, last change is that what if i only compute the vectors v1,v2,v3 inside the for loop

Comment: It seems that the for-loop approach you provide gives an error when computing `vs[i]` inside the loop?

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydf %>% 
  mutate(new = imap(a, ~ rep(.y, ceiling(10 * runif(1)))))

#>   a                          new
#> 1 1 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
#> 2 2             2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
#> 3 3       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
```